# trying to decrypt using node.js

Tags: html, node.js

I'm experimenting with decrypting and encrypting and I'm trying to display my encrypted and decrypted passwords on a webpage.

Every time I go to run the program I get:

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipher.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:164:28)
    at dec (/home/runner/aesDecoder/index.js:17:23)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/runner/aesDecoder/index.js:27:49)
    at Server.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:691:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:17)
```

My enc function works, but my decryption function does not. See my code below:

```
function enc()
{
const crypto = require('crypto');
const password ='mypassword';
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes128', 'a password');
var encrypted = cipher.update(password, 'utf8', 'hex');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
return encrypted;
}

function dec()
{
const crypto = require('crypto');
const encrypt_password = '55264cad9904196667fa97e55a29364a';
const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-cbc','a password');
var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypt_password,'hex', 'utf8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
return decrypted;
}



var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write("<h1>Encrypted password:</h1>" + enc());
response.write("<h1>Decrypted password:</h1>" + dec());
response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: When I run your `enc()` function I get `b1d7c9a7793e6d4e459e16a58140ba50` passing this back to `dec()` works. Where do you get `55264cad9904196667fa97e55a29364a`?

Comment: You might also want to consider using a random salt for your password, and a random IV for the data!

Comment: I am wanting to run 55264cad9904196667fa97e55a29364a through the dec() function and am not wanting to pass the encrypted hash back through.

Comment: As @MarkMeyer is asking: Where did you get `55264cad9904196667fa97e55a29364a` from? Was it perhaps encrypted under another encryption key?